# Getting and inserting all files inside directory to List

Tags: java, android

I'm trying get all files inside a directory and insert into a `List`, but I'm getting a error:

> add() in List cannot be applied to (Java.io.File)

Here is my code:

**fragmentList.java**

```
public List<mList> pList;



public void listf(String directoryName) {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    pList = new ArrayList<>();

    // Get all files from a directory.
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    if(fList != null)
        for (File file : fList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                pList.add(file); // THE ERROR IS HERE
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                listf(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: `List <mList> pList` - what is a `mlist` and why do you think you can add a `File` to this `List`?

Comment: mList = **mList.java**. I forget to say about this, I'll edit the thread, sorry.

Comment: I just want get all file names from directory to list

Comment: You have List<mList> which means it is a List holding type "mList:.  You want List<File> if you want to add File objects to pList.  If you just want to list file names here is what you need: https://howtodoinjava.com/java8/java-8-list-all-files-example/.   E.g. Files.list(Paths.get(".")).forEach(System.out::println);

Comment: @Karlna Please provide more information as requested.

Comment: @Karlna You have accepted an answer, which is good, but can you please add some information explaining which choice you decided to take, as it stands this question/answer is of very limited use to other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the File elements to the List

Change

```
public List<mList> pList;
```

to

```
public List<File> pList;
```

or like you stated you want to get the File names

Change

```
public List<mList> pList;
```

to

```
public List<String> pList;
```

and add the element using `file.getName();`

Comment: Do you know what a `mList` is?  Do you know whether the OP needs to use it or not?  Maybe an over-simplistic change as stated by you would work, but would it work for the OP?  I have tried to obtain more information before answering, and the OP said he would edit.

Comment: The question states they need to put `Files` into a list.

Comment: Also states *I just want get all file names from directory to list* - so maybe `List <String>` would be sufficient?

Comment: That comment was posted right after I have posted my answer, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void getFileList() {
    // list will have all files in directory.
    List<File> pList = new ArrayList<>();
    // calling listf method with directoryFull path as input 
    listf(pList, "/TESTDIR");
    // printing All files path on console 
    System.out.println(" files " + pList);

}

// Method will take directory path and list as input , It recursively collect 
// all files in directory inside pList.
public static void listf(List<File> pList, String directoryName) {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);

    // Get all files from a directory.
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    if (fList != null)
        for (File file : fList) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                pList.add(file);
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                listf(pList, file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code only answers, please explain what you have done.

Comment: Modified post as per comment.